# Authentication issues with ASP.Net/IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

I have been developing a password reset tool internally.
The tool is using windows authentication (intranet app).
This test perfectly when running locally, but when I publish to IIS and send a unlock or reset command it uses the machine account of the iis server to contact AD (which obviously then does not have the permissions to unlock or reset)

Attached is my web config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

    <dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false" />

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="*" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CCLPasswordManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PasswordManagementModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PasswordManagementModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PasswordManagementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=10.200.123.16;initial catalog=CCLPasswordManagement;persist security info=True;user id=FrameworkAPI;password=a5t3r1x!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

There must be something obvious I am missing in the config of IIS I am presuming.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is the reset password code

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(
                        ContextType.Domain))
                    {
                        string userid = userName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault();
                        if (userid != null)
                        {
                            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userid))
                            {
                                if (user != null)
                                {
                                    user.SetPassword(password);
                                    user.ExpirePasswordNow();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service account in active directory and use it. You can either use the credentials in your code, or use the Impersonation element in web.config to impersonate this service account:

`<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN\ServiceAccount" password="password"/>`.

Comment: What I am wanting is that the user that is authenticated users their credentials to do the unlocking that way we will have a trace in the AD logs.  If we use a service account like you suggest then it would be generic

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, click on your website and then the Authentication icon. Make sure Anonymous Authentication is disabled and only Windows Authentication is enabled.

Comment: yep I can confirm that is the case

Comment: How are you sending the unlock or reset command? Maybe post some code?

Comment: no problem here is the reset password code (which as I said before works locally but not on IIS)